# Unable to see my web page after moving it into different directory

Tags: php, html, web, migration, hosting

I created a new landing page and placed it in public_html directory. I am able to access it, but when I moved my older website into a new directory after creating a new directory in public_html folder, I can't access it. I create a folder with the name of ow and moved the website into it, but after entering the url mywebsite.com/ow/index.php, all I see is a blank page. I moved it back and it was visible again. I want to access both of websites at same time. I tried to rename it to index-old.php and visited mywebsite.com/index-old.php but I saw the same blank page again. It's a non-wordpress website, I have searched a lot about it but I can't find any solution. Any kind of help in this regard will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the .htaccess file? There might be something in there that is creating a problem.

Comment: I checked it but there is only one line there which says, 
RewriteEngine on